# I want to redirect my irb output into a folder of my choice such as a word file

Tags: ruby, windows, irb

so i have been trying to make a tillable list of names that will be put in alphabetic order and i got it to work but then realized this list helped me none if i didn't get it printed somewhere i could read it without the code obscuring it so i need only the output to be sent to a word / notepad file so i can use my output properly if you can help it would be EXTREMELY helpful to me please help also it may or may not help i just thought i should tell you im on windows if that changes anything

Comment: Have you looked at the `File` class at all? There is no reason to redirect irb output in this case. All you need to do is write the output you want to a `File`.

Comment: would this make it a notepad file?

Comment: like open it and it opens notepad up with the output in it

Comment: Correct something as simple as `File.open('/path/to/file.txt','w') { |f| f.puts YOUR_LIST_OF_NAMES }` will work. Since you have posted no code about the list at all a comment is probably the best I do.

Comment: hate to bother you again, I thought I could figure it out myself but couldn't the code you gave me no matter what i put in place of ' /path/to/file.txt ' it always comes back with couldn't find such directory

Comment: Then the path you are supplying is incorrect. Not sure I can help you there since I have no idea what your directory structure looks like or even what OS you are on

Comment: windows 7 and the path is Libraries\Documents\list.txt

Comment: That is not a path. That is a shortcut to your My Documents. The path would be "/Users/YOUR USER NAME/Documents/list.txt" (**note** use the forward slashes not the back slashes like you would normally on windows)